# In Vulkan how am I supposed to know if the buffer usage flag TRANSFER_SOURCE needs to be used?

Tags: vulkan

There's a bit of a chicken and the egg issue I'm dealing with. I create a buffer, and if that buffer is going to be allocated to device-local memory then there's the possibility that the memory type I can use for that buffer will NOT be host-visible, and so I need to set the VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT flag on the buffer, and use a host-visible staging buffer. The problem goes like this:

```
auto bufferUsageBits = VK_BUFFER_USAGE_VERTEX_BUFFER_BIT /* | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT*/;
// The second flag should be set only if the memory requirements queries later
// tell me there's no device-local AND host-visible memory types
VkBuffer vkBufferHandle;
VK::createBuffer(size, bufferUsageBits, VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE, &vkBufferHandle);

vkGetBufferMemoryRequirements();
// Only know do I now if I need a staging buffer and the buffer I'm creating needs to be transfered to.
```

I could do two things as far as I can see:

1. If the device is integrated or CPU type then assume that the buffer won't need the transfer flag set.
2. Set the flag anyway whether it's integrated/CPU or discrete.

How am I supposed to deal with this?

Answer (score 3):

If you create a `VkBuffer` and the memory requirements for it are such that it needs to allow being the destination of a transfer operation, then... create a new `VkBuffer` with the destination transfer usage bit set (and delete the old one).

It's just a `VkBuffer`. It doesn't really do anything until its bound to memory. Indeed, it's a good idea in a real application to create multiple speculative buffers to figure out where you intend to arrange your buffer memory usage.

Comment: But if I set only VERTEX_BUFFER_BIT, then memRequirements returns that some memory types are suitable for it. I find that none of them are host-visible, so I delete buffer and create another one with VERTEX_BUFFER_BIT and TRANSFER_DESTINATION_BIT, then I need to query memRequirements again for that buffer, right? And I may get different memory types?

Comment: @Zebrafish: Yes, you have to query memory requirements again.